# How to send data from controller to model with CodeIgniter through functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass data from Controller to model.But I am unable to fetch it at the model side in CI.Kindly help me out.

Here is my **controller** function:

```
function show_chronicles($chronicle_num) {
    $this->load->database();

    //load the model  
    $this->load->model('Chronicles_model');
    //load the method of model  

    $data['h'] = $this->Chronicles_model->show_seminar();
    //return the data in view  
    $this->load->view('chronicles', $chronicle_num);
}
```

And here is my **model**:

```
public function show_seminar($chronicle_num) {
    echo $chronicle_num;
    //$this->db->select('*');
    //$this->db->where('chronicles_no',$chronicle_num);
    //$query1 = $this->db->get('chronicles');  
    //return $query1;  
}
```

Comment: show_seminar() function has one parameter, you wont mention in controller... pass parameter from controller to model... the parameter may be your data that you have to insert into database & return data from model function to controller you store in $data['h'].( add return stmt in model function)

Answer (score 3):

Its because your not passing any value to your model.

**CONTROLLER**

```
function show_chronicles($chronicle_num)
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->load->model('Chronicles_model');  

    $data['h']=$this->Chronicles_model->show_seminar($chronicle_num);  
    $this->load->view('chronicles', $chronicle_num);

}
```

and you need to return the `result()` of your query

**MODEL**

```
public function show_seminar($chronicle_num = NULL)
      {  
         return $this->db
                     ->get_where('chronicles', array('chronicles_no' => $chronicle_num))
                     ->result();  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**:

```
function show_chronicles($chronicle_num) {
    $this->load->database();

    //load the model  
    $this->load->model('Chronicles_model');
    //load the method of model  

    // pass it to model
    $data['chronicle_num'] = $this->Chronicles_model->show_seminar($chronicle_num);
    //return the data in view  
    $this->load->view('chronicles', $data);
}
```

And here is my **model**:

```
public function show_seminar($chronicle_num) {
    return $chronicle_num;
    //$this->db->select('*');
    //$this->db->where('chronicles_no',$chronicle_num);
    //$query1 = $this->db->get('chronicles');  
    //return $query1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to pass `$chronicle_num` as a parameter when you called `$this->Chronicles_model->show_seminar();`.

So the right way is `$this->Chronicles_model->show_seminar($chronicle_num);`

You can add as many parameters as you wish to the functions. Example:

```
public function show_seminar($chronicle_num, $param2, $param3) {
    //Login here
}
```

Just remember to pass the parameters every time you call the function.